# Dacpac deployment failed with partition scheme changes

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, dacpac, sqlpackage

We are deploying our dacpac with changes to a partition scheme and function. During the deployment we get an error

> Invalid partition scheme '...' specified

When we look at the deployment script we see that the partition scheme is first dropped, then a temporary table 'tmp_ms_xx_...' is created with a reference to the partition schema that was just dropped!?
At the end of the script we see that the partition scheme is created.

Does anyone know why the script is generated this way resulting in an obvious error?

Comment: Sure seems like a bug in the dacpac deployment process; I'd file it if I were you. That said, what is the nature of the changes in your partition function/scheme? The tooling seems to _love_ doing "swing all of the data into a temporary table" type moves where I as the operator could come up with a less expensive way to do it. Perhaps that's the case here too? All that said, I'm surprised that even with a size-of-data change that the tooling didn't create the temporary table on the new partition function/scheme.